# How to make the settings for Download in Firefox when launched using Webdriver?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have set this option in my Firefox for **Downloads**. But each time I am opening the Firefox using Webdriver it is set to **Save files to** Downloads. So whenever there is a file which is to be downloaded from Firefox launched by Webdriver, it will save to default location.

What can I do so that it always asks me for Download location when launched using webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following code snippet:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a firefox profile like this:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

In this profile, set the correct download destination.Now in your code when you create the firefox driver, start it with the newly created profile. This should do the trick.

Comment: This is also having a drawback that if any firefox instance is opened normally without using webdriver and we try to open firefox using webdriver, it will throw an exception of the profile file being locked.